# Ajustar Paneles Automaticamente

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes, este día mi pregunta es un tanto simple pero no se como resolverlo, estoy creando un `windows forms` principal, en el que tengo dos `panel`, y los cuales requiero se ajusten de forma automatica a la resolución de mi pantalla sin tener que modificar todo el tamaño de mi `form` y estar jugando con los tamaños.

Si alguien sabe como hacerlo le estare muy agradecido saludos.

Comment: Hola Alberto, creo que ya llevas suficiente tiempo en el sitio para saber que se necesita incluir el código en la pregunta.

Comment: No es código como tal son herramientas que uso del cuadro de herramientas.

Comment: Windows Forms carece de muchas herramientas para poder ajustar los elementos automáticamente a la resolución. Lo único de lo que dispone y es lo que yo he utilizado normalmente es el [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd492143.aspx). En el enlace tienes ejemplos de como usarlo. La otra opción es pasarse a una tecnología mas moderna, como WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Sería mas fácil si colocaras una imagen del formulario con los páneles para tener una mejor idea de lo que quieres hacer.

Pero bueno, lo que entiendo es que, si cambias la resolución, los páneles se ven, o muy grandes, o muy pequeños, y quieres que siempre se vean del mismo tamaño, independientemente de la resolución de pantalla.

Si es eso lo que quieres, tienes que reajustar los tamaños obteniendo el radio de aspecto, por ejemplo en esta respuesta dan el siguiente código: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802015/controls-resize-based-on-screen-resolution

Primero guardas el alto y ancho de la pantalla en pixeles:

```
int i_StandardHeight = 768;// la resolución de pantalla (alto en pixeles) inicial
                int i_StandardWidth = 1024; ;// resolución de pantalla (ancho en pixeles) al iniciar la aplicación
```

Y cuando redibujes los páneles:

```
                int i_PresentHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
                int i_PresentWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
                float f_HeightRatio = new float();
                float f_WidthRatio = new float();
                f_HeightRatio = (float)((float)i_PresentHeight / (float)i_StandardHeight);
                f_WidthRatio = (float)((float)i_PresentWidth / (float)i_StandardWidth);
                foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.Button")
                    {
                        Button obtn = (Button)c;
                        obtn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    }
                    if (c.HasChildren)
                    {
                        foreach (Control cChildren in c.Controls)
                        {
                            cChildren.SetBounds(Convert.ToInt32(cChildren.Bounds.X * f_WidthRatio), Convert.ToInt32(cChildren.Bounds.Y * f_WidthRatio), Convert.ToInt32(cChildren.Bounds.Width * f_WidthRatio), Convert.ToInt32(cChildren.Bounds.Height * f_HeightRatio));
                            //cChildren.Font = new Font(cChildren.Font.FontFamily, cChildren.Font.Size * f_HeightRatio, cChildren.Font.Style, cChildren.Font.Unit, ((byte)(0)));
                        }
                        c.SetBounds(Convert.ToInt32(c.Bounds.X * f_WidthRatio), Convert.ToInt32(c.Bounds.Y * f_WidthRatio), Convert.ToInt32(c.Bounds.Width * f_WidthRatio), Convert.ToInt32(c.Bounds.Height * f_HeightRatio));
                       // c.Font = new Font(c.Font.FontFamily, c.Font.Size * f_HeightRatio, c.Font.Style, c.Font.Unit, ((byte)(0)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        c.SetBounds(Convert.ToInt32(c.Bounds.X * f_WidthRatio), Convert.ToInt32(c.Bounds.Y * f_WidthRatio), Convert.ToInt32(c.Bounds.Width * f_WidthRatio), Convert.ToInt32(c.Bounds.Height * f_HeightRatio));
                       // c.Font = new Font(c.Font.FontFamily, c.Font.Size * f_HeightRatio, c.Font.Style, c.Font.Unit, ((byte)(0)));
                    }
                }
                this.Height = Convert.ToInt32(i_StandardHeight * f_HeightRatio);
                this.Width = Convert.ToInt32(i_StandardWidth * f_WidthRatio);
```

Ya solo tienes que capturar el evento de cambio de resolución y ahí redibujar los páneles:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged
```

Pero si lo que quieres es que los páneles se mantengan siempre en un lugar y con un espaciado aunque cambie el tamaño del formulario, puedes jugar con la propiedad 'Anchor' o meter los páneles en un TableLayoutPanel.